# Происхождение слова "урка"

Tags: этимология, жаргон

Думаю, все знают (хотя бы из песни "Мурка"), что на уголовном жаргоне воры называются урками. Но интересно было бы узнать, откуда это слово взялось? Оно что-то означает, или это, как и "зэк", - какая-то аббревиатура?
Заранее спасибо за ответ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть несколько версий. Первая – от словосочетаний "уголовник-рецедивист" или, более вероятная, "урочный каторжанин". Вторая — заимствование из идиша ("урем" - бедняк) или тюркизм ("ур(к)" - вор).  В точности последних двух не уверен, но в целом смысл, думаю, понятен.

Answer (score 3):

Я бы склонился к версии об урочном арестанте. Хочу поделиться имеющейся в моей голове информацией. Авторитетные урки наносили себе татуировки - коты, - это знак вора в законе, а коты, как известно, урчат. Это, скорее всего, просто совпадение, но Мурка - точно отсюда.

Comment: А что такое урочный арестант?

Comment: Думаю, это связано со словами срок и сверхурочно.

Answer (score 0):

Уголовник-рецидивист - это урка!
Понятие появилось после войны.
Так себя называли те, кто сидел за уголовные преступления большие сроки или неск. сроков и жили по законам воровской жизни.
Урка - несоветский человек, не строитель коммунизма.
Зэка - просто заключенный, это официоз и для зоны, и для тех, кто просто живет рядом.
Урки считали себя элитой зэка.
Источник информации - дядя, бывший нквдешником в 1940-1960 гг.

Comment: Это мы более или менее и без вашего дяди-энкавэдэшника установили. Хотя и есть сомнения в сроках появления. А вы не могли бы спросить дядю, откуда само слова взялось? Не на пустом же месте появилось?

Answer (score 0):

Песня "Мурка", близкая к современному варианту, появилась уже в 20-х годах. Упоминаемая в тексте ГубЧК существовала до 22-го года, после этого переименовавшись в ГПУ. Так что все версии, связанные с после- и предвоенным происхождением слова - маловероятны))))

Существует несколько версий, откуда произошло это жаргонное слово. Одни источники указывают, что в XIX веке ссыльнокаторжных, которые днем выполняли тяжелые работы на лесоповале или рудниках, называли «урочными каторжанами». Сокращенно — урка (ур-ка). Урочные каторжане отличались от бессрочных (сосланных навечно) тем, что могли отбыть наказание и вернуться туда, где раньше жили. Обычно такие уголовники после первого срока опять шли воровать и в очередной раз оказывались на каторге. С тех пор это значение слова закрепилось и стало использоваться для обозначения всех преступников-рецидивистов.

По другой версии, слово «урка» происходит от древнего тюркского корня «ур». Он входит в состав казахских слов «уры», «урлык», которые буквально обозначают «вор», «грабеж». В тюркском языке слово «урк» обозначает свирепого, очень опасного человека. «Уркаган» в тюркском выглядит как два слова: «ур» и «каган», что буквально обозначает страшного главу, то есть вожака банды, атамана, главного вора.

Еще одна версия происхождения этого слова связана с традиционной для всего воровского жаргона этимологией. Слово «урка» позаимствовано из языка евреев, живших и процветавших когда-то в Одессе. В этом портовом городе в прошлом веке не только буйным цветом расцвела еврейская мафия, но и сформировался сам воровской язык с его колоритными словечками, которые знал весь Советский Союз. На иврите слово «урка» обозначает человека, находящегося за решеткой, преступника.

Answer (score 0):

Всплыл это вопрос, на который я в свое время почему-то не удосужился ответить.

Для начала. Мурка - это Мура, Мария. Обычное имя. Возводить к чему-то еще просто глупо.

Вот с урками посложнее. Как и почти все слова уголовного жаргона оно не имеет однозначной этимологии и вполне может считаться смешением или даже конкатенацией разных понятий, близких только фонетически.

При этом слово (в форме, правда, несколько иной) фиксируется с очень давних пор. Хотя это возможно, просто совпадение.

Более или менее полный список всех правдоподобных версий обнаружил здесь.
https://news.rambler.ru/other/37463747-urka-otkuda-vzyalos-eto-slovo/?article_index=1&updated

Весь ответ @Lans - цитата из этого источника.

Мне особо нечего добавить. Правда, все версии не слишком достоверные. Особенно большое сомнение вызывает существование в иврите слова "урка", но что-то похоже, возможно, есть.

И коли уж тут и само слово Зек стало обсуждаться, то дополню картину цитатой из самого доступного источника.

> Происходит от обозначения «з/к», использовавшегося в официальных
> документах в период с конца 1920-х по конец 1950-х годов.
> Этимологически восходит к сокращению от «Заключённый каналоармеец»,
> впервые появившегося во время строительства Беломорско-Балтийского
> канала.

https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%B7%D1%8D%D0%BA
Интересной тут является отсылка к совершенно забытому словечку "каналоармеец".

Answer (score -1):

Как версия: очень часто в личных делах уголовников 30—40-х гг. на фотографиях попадается штамп УРКМ — Управления рабоче-крестьянской милиции ОГПУ СССР (1932—1934).

Comment: А в чем "версия" состоит? Урка - от УРКМ? Сильно...

Answer (score -2):

УРКА - аббревиатура, уголовный рецидивист,криминальный авторитет.